# Reorganice (and style) form's output in HTML using JQuery: how to do it better?

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, html

To clarify: The code in "What I achieved" is working. I'm looking for suggestions so I can improve.

I'm quite new with JQuery (and javascript) and I've been learning while styling a forum. Recently I came across a section of information that is added automatically from a form (its the output). I can't manipulate the HTML directly and I wanted to change the style of that output to go with my design. So I decided to use JQuery (and css) to accomplish this.

The code that I wrote works just fine, however I know it's not the cleanest nor the more efficient way. I thought maybe you could give me some feedback on the JQuery code. For example, the part where I delete the 'Race' and 'Other activity' tags: would be set in just one loop using a for or each? or, since its a code that will be in all the pages of the site, does it matter if I wrap all the code in just one function or its ok just like that?

Some notes:

- All the Values (Value_1, Value_2, …) may change, they are the answers of the users. They can be numbers or text.
- The Output of the form is the code in the "Original" class. The HTML structure is already written and I cannot change that. The rest of the HTML (.info, p, .moreinfo) was added by me.
- The "What I want to achieve" is the html/css style that I created to go with the design of the site.

So what I have initially is this:

```
<div class="info">

<div class="original"><span class="label"><span style="color:#D0C6C4;">Race</span> : </span>Value_1<span class="label"><span style="color:#D0C6C4;">Age</span> : </span>Value_2<span class="label"><span style="color:#536482;">Nationality</span> : </span>Value_3<span class="label"><span style="color:#536482;">Points</span> : </span>Value_4<span class="label"><span style="color:#536482;">Messages</span> : </span>Value_5<span class="label"><span style="color:#536482;">Other activity</span> : </span>Value_6</div>

<p></p>
</div>
<div class="moreinfo"></div>
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
<div class="info">
  <div class="pair">
    <strong>Age</strong><span>Value_2</span>
    <strong>Nationality</strong><span>Value_3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="pair">
    <strong>Points</strong><span>Value_4</span>
    <strong>Messages</strong><span>Value_5</span>
  </div>
                    
  <p>Value_1</p>
</div>

<div class="moreinfo">Value_6</div>
```

What I achieved:

```
<div class="info">
  <div class="pair">
    <span class="span-0">Age</span><span class="value span-1">Value_2</span>
    <span class="span-2">Nationality</span><span class="value span-3">Value_3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="pair">
    <span class="span-0">Points</span><span class="value span-1">Value_4</span>
    <span class="span-2">Messages</span><span class="value span-3">Value_5</span>
  </div>
                    
  <p>Value_1</p>
</div>

<div class="moreinfo">Value_6</div>
```

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 //First I deleted de attributes and the ":"
 $('.original span').each(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('style');
   $(this).removeClass();
   
   var label = $(this).text();
   label = label.replace(' : ','');
   $(this).html(label);
 });
 
 //Wrap the text that is alone (without tags) inside .original
 $('.original').contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType !=1}).wrap('<span class="value"></span>');
  
 //Deleted 'Race' and 'Other activity' spans, and positioned the info related to them (Value_1 and Value_6) to the place I want
 $('.original span').each(function() {
  label = $(this).text();
  if(label == 'Race'){
     var race = $(this).next().text();
     $('.info p').append(race);
     $(this).next().remove();
     $(this).remove();
   };
  if(label == 'Other activity'){
    var job = $(this).next().text();
    $('.moreinfo').append(job);
    $(this).next().remove();
    $(this).remove();
  }
});

//Wrap in pairs
var set = $('.original').children();
for(var i=0, len = set.length; i < len; i+=4){
  set.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll('<div class="pair"></div>');};

//Add extra class for each <span> so I can later style the grid-area in CSS
$('.pair').each(function() {
  $(this).children().addClass(function(index){return 'span-' + index});
});

//"Deleted" the .original div
$('.info > .original').contents().unwrap();
});
```

The CSS:

```
.info {
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.info .pair {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "a b" "c d";
    column-gap: 10px;
    row-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.pair span.span-0 {grid-area: a;}
.pair span.span-2 {grid-area: b;}
.pair span.span-1 {grid-area: c;}
.pair span.span-3 {grid-area: d;}

.info span.value {
    background-color: #111;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.pair span.span-0, .pair span.span-2 {
    color: salmon;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: for starters I would you should use `output` and `label` instead of using spans when you have dedicated semantic tags for it.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks! However in this case, if you are referring to the class   `original`, I can't do much. The forum is giving me that automatically and I cannot change that part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Some quick suggestions after reviewing your code:

1. **Chain jQuery methods**: You can chain methods to reduce the number of times you traverse the DOM.
2. **Use `.text()` instead of `.html()`**: If you're not dealing with HTML tags, it's safer to use `.text()`.
3. **Use `.filter()`**: You can use `.filter()` to remove specific elements based on their text content.
4. **Use `.appendTo()` and `.remove()`**: Instead of `.append()` and `.next().remove()`, you can directly move elements.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful! About Chaining in JQuery, I just realice I had a misconception about it. So… if I understood right, is it correct then to write, for example: `$(this).removeAttr('style').removeClass();` instead of `$(this).removeAttr('style'); $(this).removeClass();`, right?